# How do I skip reading a line in a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

The file contains the following data:

```
#10000000    AAA 22.145  21.676  21.588
10  TTT 22.145  21.676  21.588
1  ACC 22.145  21.676  21.588
```

I tried to skip lines starting with "#" using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
     while( getline("myfile.txt", qlline)) {

           stringstream sq(qlline);
           int tableEntry;

           sq >> tableEntry;

          if (tableEntry.find("#") != tableEntry.npos) {
              continue;
          }

          int data = tableEntry;
   }
}
```

But for some reason it gives this error:

> Mycode.cc:13: error: request for
>   member 'find' in 'tableEntry', which
>   is of non-class type 'int'

Comment: +1 for the compiler.  what part of the error didn't you understand?

Comment: xtofl: Dude if I could +1 a comment, laughed my ass off :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this more like what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    fstream fin("myfile.txt");
    string line;
    while(getline(fin, line)) 
    {
        //the following line trims white space from the beginning of the string
        line.erase(line.begin(), find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace)))); 

        if(line[0] == '#') continue;

        int data;
        stringstream(line) >> data;

        cout << "Data: " << data  << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest trimming the line before checking for comment characters.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the example to trim the start of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You try to extract an integer from the line, and then try to find a "#" in the integer. This doesn't make sense, and the compiler complains that there is no `find` method for integers.

You probably should check the "#" directly on the read line at the beginning of the loop.
Besides that you need to declare `qlline` and actually open the file somewhere and not just pass a string with it's name to `getline`. Basically like this:

```
ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
string qlline;
while (getline(myfile, qlline)) {
  if (qlline.find("#") == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  ...
}
```